# Google Analytics not logging hits in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using GA to track screen views in my app. The problem is that, although the debug log says that the hits have been successfully dispatched, they are not appearing in the GA. It's not just the real time view. They don't appear at all. I've tried GA v3.0.2, 3.0.3c and 3.0.9 on iOS7 and iOS8. I've tried creating new account on GA or using the one from before (it worked in GA v2).

I'm initializing GA like this:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DISPATCH_INTERVAL;

[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID_IPHONE];
[[GAI sharedInstance] setDefaultTracker:self.tracker];

[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAISampleRate value:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SAMPLE_RATE];
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIAnonymizeIp value:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ANONYMIZE];

[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:@""];    
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3] value:[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker get:kGAIClientId]];

[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"UX"
                                                       action:@"appstart"
                                                        label:nil
                                                        value:nil] set:@"start" forKey:kGAISessionControl] build]];
```

The log (captured with v3.09)

```
2014-10-08 11:56:38.752 Lauritz[321:45873] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:431): Saved hit: {
parameters =     {
    "&_crc" = 0;
    "&_u" = ".ojL";
    "&_v" = "mi3.0.9";
    "&a" = 2011837377;
    "&aid" = "com.lauritz.ios.chair";
    "&aip" = YES;
    "&an" = Lauritz;
    "&av" = "1.2.1";
    "&cd" = "lauritzapp/view/loading-page";
    "&cd1" = "a8f7a271770289ac72babc1cfad2966ef8e02c757de427fffbbc702845253e30-test";
    "&cd3" = "3d6b3c54-650d-4501-9d1f-0a6078d921fc";
    "&cid" = "3d6b3c54-650d-4501-9d1f-0a6078d921fc";
    "&sf" = 100;
    "&sr" = 320x568;
    "&t" = timing;
    "&tid" = "UA-948120-10";
    "&ul" = en;
    "&utc" = API;
    "&utl" = Success;
    "&utt" = "0.2104618549346924";
    "&utv" = "http://193.238.185.163/json/api/v1.1/downtime/prod/eng/1026790";
    "&v" = 1;
    "&z" = 2286094286496569613;
    gaiVersion = "3.09";
};
timestamp = "2014-10-08 09:56:38 +0000";
}
2014-10-08 11:56:39.128 Lauritz[321:45817] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:completionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:161): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2014-10-08 11:56:39.130 Lauritz[321:45873] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:443): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
2014-10-08 11:56:39.133 Lauritz[321:45873] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:sendMore:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:174): 1 hit(s) sent
2014-10-08 11:56:39.136 Lauritz[321:45873] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2014-10-08 11:56:39.136 Lauritz[321:45873] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:536): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?an=Lauritz&cd1=a8f7a271770289ac72babc1cfad2966ef8e02c757de427fffbbc702845253e30-test&a=2011837377&cd=lauritzapp%2Fview%2Floading-page&av=1.2.1&t=screenview&_crc=0&ul=en&cd3=3d6b3c54-650d-4501-9d1f-0a6078d921fc&tid=UA-948120-10&cid=3d6b3c54-650d-4501-9d1f-0a6078d921fc&sr=320x568&aip=YES&v=1&_u=.K-L&aid=com.lauritz.ios.chair&_v=mi3.0.9&sf=100&ht=1412762194460&qt=4675&z=2286094286496569612
2014-10-08 11:56:39.229 Lauritz[321:45817] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:completionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:161): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2014-10-08 11:56:39.230 Lauritz[321:45873] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:443): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
2014-10-08 11:56:39.232 Lauritz[321:45873] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:sendMore:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:174): 1 hit(s) sent
2014-10-08 11:56:39.236 Lauritz[321:45873] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2014-10-08 11:56:39.236 Lauritz[321:45873] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:536): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?utv=http%3A%2F%2F193.238.185.163%2Fjson%2Fapi%2Fv1.1%2Fdowntime%2Fprod%2Feng%2F1026790&utc=API&ul=en&cd3=3d6b3c54-650d-4501-9d1f-0a6078d921fc&tid=UA-948120-10&utt=0.2104618549346924&_v=mi3.0.9&cid=3d6b3c54-650d-4501-9d1f-0a6078d921fc&an=Lauritz&cd1=a8f7a271770289ac72babc1cfad2966ef8e02c757de427fffbbc702845253e30-test&a=2011837377&_crc=0&sr=320x568&t=timing&utl=Success&cd=lauritzapp%2Fview%2Floading-page&aip=YES&v=1&_u=.ojL&sf=100&aid=com.lauritz.ios.chair&av=1.2.1&ht=1412762198748&qt=487&z=2286094286496569613
2014-10-08 11:56:39.325 Lauritz[321:45817] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:completionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:161): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2014-10-08 11:56:39.326 Lauritz[321:45873] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:443): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
2014-10-08 11:56:39.329 Lauritz[321:45873] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:sendMore:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:174): 1 hit(s) sent
```

Here's the code I use for sending hits:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"page"];
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

As far as I can tell everything is working fine and hits are successfully dispatched. The problem is that they don't show in GA. As I said, it's not only for real time view. The hits from yesterday haven't shown up either so it's not a question of waiting for them to be processed by Google.

Any ideas?

Comment: some time is not show , k can u show ur hit method

Comment: try to set this property [GAI sharedInstance].optOut and check then.

Comment: Added code I use for sending hits. I've also tried optOut but, as expected, no result. The app was sending hits all along (as you can see from the log). It's just that they are not shown.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this, @IvanPavlović? I have the same issue!

Comment: Not yet. But when I find it I'll update the question

Comment: Any luck? I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with Google Analytics

Comment: I have the same issue too! The logs look like it is working, but nothing showing up.

Comment: Actually after a few weeks everything started working with no change to the code whatsoever. I did go through the setup and the client hasn't accepted one of the data collection agreements. It might've been that? I've also noticed that after you create a new account live data will not show up for some time (a day or so) but it starts working normally afterwards